# Understanding REST API response

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Say you query a `ListItem` from the `API` `_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)`

and Let's say the item is a `Page`, and the `Response` looks like below.

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "ce0f35a3-0644-4346-8819-52ec87d70f91",
            "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)",
            "etag": "\"4\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.SitePagesItem"
        },
        "FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"
            }
        },
        "RoleAssignments": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/RoleAssignments"
            }
        },
        "AttachmentFiles": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles"
            }
        },
        "ContentType": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/ContentType"
            }
        },
        "FieldValuesAsHtml": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml"
            }
        },
        "FieldValuesAsText": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsText"
            }
        },
        "FieldValuesForEdit": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/FieldValuesForEdit"
            }
        },
        "File": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/File"
            }
        },
        "Folder": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/Folder"
            }
        },
        "ParentList": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/ParentList"
            }
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x01010800A17AD719CAA5FD488DE4BE6975C27838",
        "WikiField": "<div class=\"ExternalClassF6F68F52E1E4476EAC56AA39304E040F\">\r\n            <table id=\"layoutsTable\" style=\"width&#58;100%;\">\r\n                <tbody>\r\n                    <tr style=\"vertical-align&#58;top;\">\r\n            <td colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-outer\" style=\"width&#58;100%;\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-inner\" style=\"word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read e572e784-7389-4c16-b560-b23a3f5f8c6f\" id=\"div_e572e784-7389-4c16-b560-b23a3f5f8c6f\"></div>\n  <div class=\"ms-rtestate-read\" id=\"vid_e572e784-7389-4c16-b560-b23a3f5f8c6f\" style=\"display&#58;none;\"></div>\n</div>\n</div></div></td>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                    <tr style=\"vertical-align&#58;top;\">\r\n            <td style=\"width&#58;49.95%;\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-outer\" style=\"width&#58;100%;\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-inner\" style=\"word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read 37952ec8-18c0-480f-9427-98988341f8e7\" id=\"div_37952ec8-18c0-480f-9427-98988341f8e7\"></div>\n  <div class=\"ms-rtestate-read\" id=\"vid_37952ec8-18c0-480f-9427-98988341f8e7\" style=\"display&#58;none;\"></div>\n</div>\n</div></div></td>\r\n            <td class=\"ms-wiki-columnSpacing\" style=\"width&#58;49.95%;\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-outer\" style=\"width&#58;100%;\"><div class=\"ms-rte-layoutszone-inner\" style=\"word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read 0f00075e-2352-43d8-8477-f2fb51cf2739\" id=\"div_0f00075e-2352-43d8-8477-f2fb51cf2739\"></div>\n  <div class=\"ms-rtestate-read\" id=\"vid_0f00075e-2352-43d8-8477-f2fb51cf2739\" style=\"display&#58;none;\"></div>\n</div>\n</div></div></td>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                </tbody>\r\n            </table>\r\n            <span id=\"layoutsData\" style=\"display&#58;none;\">true,false,2</span></div>",
        "Title": null,
        "ID": 1,
        "Created": "2014-09-01T05:48:04Z",
        "AuthorId": 1073741823,
        "Modified": "2014-09-01T05:48:18Z",
        "EditorId": 1073741823,
        "OData__CopySource": null,
        "CheckoutUserId": null,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "GUID": "2f0c04dc-dfa7-4154-8e87-d11d5d91cbf6"
    }
}
```

I was trying to find document to explain the response structure in the `MSDN`.

So far I didn't found any read. I try to understand like below .but I am not sure if it 
is right . Please help to review it .

1. The ["d"]["__metadata"]["uri"] represents the RestAPI url of request to query the current `ListItem`?
2. The ["__deferred"]["uri"] represent the RestAPI url to query other information of `ListItem`. eg: `File` url is `"https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c5689c37-a28a-4122-bedb-b2ec7c44204f')/Items(1)/File`?
3. Some of the properties like `Created`,`Id` etc can be returned from query. But some of the properties like `ContentType` need to be query with `uri` to know the detail.Right ?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please find the comments below:

1. `["d"]["__metadata"]["uri"]` represents the REST Endpoint url of the resource, in your case of List Item resource, e.g. `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<list guid>')/Items(<item id>)`
2. `["__deferred"]["uri"]` REST endpoint url of the resource it represents, e.g. `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<list guid>')/Items(<item id>)/File` for File resource
3. See the section below.

### Deferred properties in SharePoint REST

Deferred properties (like `File` for `List Item` resource) are not retrieved by default (first of all, for performance reasons). There are two options how to retrieve deferred properties:

- perform a separate request, for example for File resource: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list name>')/items(<item id>)/File`
- utilize `$expand` query option to request the projected properties.
  The following example demonstrates how to request List Item with File
  property initialized:

  /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[list name]')/items([item id])?$expand=File

### What properties could be retrieved using SharePoint REST

Unfortunately SharePoint REST does not support to retrieve some properties like Publishing fields. For example, in your case for Page item, `PublishingPageImage` property could not be retrieved directly via SharePoint REST.

### References

- [SHAREPOINT COLUMNS AVAILABLE VIA REST](http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/#columns)
- [OData Spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/)

VGR

Comment: +1 I am trying to search it in the MSDN. But didn't found. Please give me some link of it to read. thanks.

Comment: Regarding documentation, you might find this article http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/#columns usefull, it describes what fields are exposed via SharePoint REST inteface

Comment: Got it, Good Post ,It seems `expand`,`select` etc is from `OData Specification` .Right?

Comment: That's right, http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, if you include the REST method `$select` you'll get more data for the columns you specify.